# RouteConfig does not seem to work in my angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to use the RouteConfig in my Angular2 application. Right now, I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

My App component is using the ***router-outlet*** thing, but it dosen't work.

I have created a main.ts file which bootstrap my application:

**Main.ts**

```ts
import {provide, enableProdMode, Injectable, Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap, ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

const ENV_PROVIDERS = [];

if ('production' === process.env.ENV) {
  enableProdMode();
} else {
  ENV_PROVIDERS.push(ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS);
}

import {App} from './app/app';

/*
 * Bootstrap our Angular app with a top level component `App` and inject
 * our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
 */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function main() {
  bootstrap(App, [ENV_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,  RouteConfig, provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }) ])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

});
```

**App component**

```ts
// Bootstrapping imports
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig } from  'angular2/router';
import { Injectable, provide, Component, ViewEncapsulation } from 'angular2/core';

// Import components
import {AmendmentComponent} from '../Components/amendmentComponent';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
<div>
    <div class="header wrapper">
        <header class="row">
            <div class="column small-12">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="/assets/img/logo.svg" title="" />
                </a>
                <a class="navigation-toggle icon-menu hide-for-large-up" (click)="toggleMenuState()" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <div class="footer wrapper">
        <footer class="row">
            <div class="column small-12">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="icon icon-ship hide-for-medium-down"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
`,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
styles: [`
    app {
        display: block;
    }
`]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: ["Amendment"] },
    { path: '/amendment/...', name: 'Amendment', component: AmendmentComponent, useAsDefault: true },
])

export class App {
    angularclassLogo = 'assets/img/favicon.ico';
    name = 'AmendmentFront';
    url = '';

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

When a user enters the address: localhost:3000 or localhost:3000/amendment, it should load the AmendmentComponent component, but nothing happens, I can see the header and the footer, but nothing in the middle where i had the router-outlet.

What am I doing wrong?

After some discussion with a user, I'm getting these errors:

> Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterOutlet -> Router).
>    Child routes are not allowed for "/amendment". Use "..." on the parent's route path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular got more rigid with one of the last alpha or first beta versions about invalid HTML. `<img ... />` is not valid in HTML5 even though browsers try to interpret it the way the developer intended it. It can result in unintended results and therefore Angular doesn't try to be too forgiving anymore.

Also add `useAsDefault: true` to one route.

Comment: Have tried to remove the image complete from the side, dosen't change a thing.. the router-outlet still dosen't seem to load the other component.

Comment: only one route is allowed. If i remove the second line in the routeconfig, it dosen't give me an error, but i still need to load it if the user is typing localhost:3000/amendment?

Comment: I'm not sure at all.. I removed some code and replaced it , and that did the trick.

This is the code im using now

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: ["Amendment"] },
    { path: '/amendment/...', name: 'Amendment', component: AmendmentComponent, useAsDefault: true }
])

And its the same as before. so i dont get it :S